# Manipular elemento webcontrol dinamicamente

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Existe como manipular webcontrols name dinamicamente?**

**ex:**
tenho 90 TextBox

textBox_01_name

textBox_02_name

textBox_03_name

textBox_04_name

...

hoje tenho o seguinte código

```
if (textBox_01_name.Text != Topo_DAraay[0].ValueDefaultSQL)
{
```

para cada elemento.
Pensei em fazer um `for` e assim ir só mudando o `"textBox_" + i + "_name"`
Claro que assim não funciona mas existe alguma forma?

Consigo fazer dessa maneira, mas o código ficaria tão grande quanto o original

```
string campo = "textBox_" + i "_name";
TextBox teste1 = (TextBox)FindControl(campo);
if (teste1.Text != Topo_DAraay[0].ValueDefaultSQL)
{
```

Existe alguma forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você mesmo quase respondeu a pergunta. Se usando `FindControl` pode achar um controle no contexto em que está, poderá então achar os outros controles, fazendo um `for` e concatenando strings dentro do mesmo:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 90; i++)
{
    string nomeControle = "textBox_" + i.ToString("00") "_name";
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)FindControl(nomeControle);
    if (txtBox.Text != Topo_DAraay[0].ValueDefaultSQL)
    {
        // sua lógica aqui!
    }
}
```

Seria isso? Não entendi o motivo de você falar que dessa forma ficaria tão grande quanto o original... vai ficar bem menor, pois vai poder aplicar a mesma lógica a todos os controles, sem replicar código.

Comment: é..esta correto..acho que preciso de férias...não tinha conseguido ver...

Comment: Que isso... acontece comigo o tempo todo! hehe =D